# MBP strange blackouts

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I have noticed, that sometimes, my MacBook Pro mid-2012 has strange blackouts like if the battery ran out. This happens even when my battery is near full. The symptoms are that the screen goes black suddenly, and that persists for about 15 seconds, before I hear audio (if there is audio running before blackout), and then it goes back to normal.

Before this started happening, I had similar blackouts because I accidentally put my mouse on a screen-saver hot corner, but now it happens even if I see my mouse in the middle of the screen.

When this blackout happens, the network disconnects for the time of the blackout too.

Why is this? What can I do to troubleshoot this issue?

---

The blackouts persist. At the time of the blackout, I see strange kernel messages in the console log:

```
08.02.16 15:02:38,000 kernel[0]: [0x10e71ae000, 0x8000]
```

Something in the format of this, with different memory addresses. At the end, there is a:

```
08.02.16 15:02:38,000 kernel[0]: *** kernel exceeded 500 log message per second limit  -  remaining messages this second discarded ***
```

---

Another update, that sometimes these blackouts are very frequent, but last 4 seconds. And other times, they happen every 5 minutes and happen for half a minute.

Answer (score 1):

It may be a GPU issue: [check to see](https://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/) if your MacBook Pro that may have been manufactured with a defective GPU.

Comment: I doubt that it was manufactured with a bad GPU. I have it for like 2 years and the problems started appearing today. Also, the light on the side makes it look like a sleep, since doing nothing doesn't wake the MBP until I spam a key on the keyboard

Comment: @TheBro21 Strange, I'm not sure what's going on then. It can't hurt to check though.

Comment: Restart made it go away. If it persists, I'll record logs at the time of the blackout